# How to switch/change testInstrumentationRunner dynamically with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

My project has 2 different groups of tests. One group runs only with the default `AndroidJUnitRunner` the other has to be run with a custom implementation `TestRunner extends MonitoringInstrumentation`.

Currently I switch the `testInstrumentationRunner` by editing the `build.gradle` each time I need to run the other group of tests:

```
android{
      defaultConfig {
          //testInstrumentationRunner "my.custom.TestRunner"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
}
```

I know that flavours can have their own `testInstrumentationRunner` but my current app already has 2 `flavourDimensions`. Using flavours is actually intended to have different versions of an app. I need 2 versions of the test application, both testing the same app with different `testInstrumentationRunner`s.

I tried to change the `testInstrumentationRunner` by iterating over all test variants. There are actually multiple `testInstrumentationRunner` properties:

```
android.testVariants.all { TestVariant variant ->
    //readonly
    variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.instrumentationRunner

    variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner

}
```

But as soon as `android.testVariants` is called the build gets configured and all changes are not reflected in the build.

How can I change the testInstrumentationRunner (from a gradle plugin) dynamically?

I'd prefer to have 2 different gradle tasks, each using a different `testInstrumentationRunner` but testing the same variant. Because I intent to create a gradle plugin the solution should work as plugin too.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered using console parameter as a switch between two configurations? As simple as that:

```
android {
      defaultConfig {
           if (project.ext.has("customRunner")) {
               testInstrumentationRunner "my.custom.TestRunner"
           } else {
               testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           }
      }
}
```

And then for example run `gradlew aDeb -PcustomRunner` if you want to test using custom runner or `gradlew aDeb` to use default.

I know it's not rocket science but simpler is better, right? You can use it in your plugin too, just obtain the Project object and do the similar thing.

Comment: how to write the same thing in Android.mk file? any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this switch from Android Studio run configuration?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972581/how-to-pass-a-parameter-in-run-debug-configuration-from-android-studio

Comment: Can you please take a look the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198163/gradle-how-to-execute-both-testinstrumentationrunners-at-the-same-time

Comment: Can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163964/how-to-combine-different-testinstrumentationrunner

Answer (score 5):

Since the android gradle plugin 1.3 it is possible to create separate test modules. Each of those test modules can have its own testInstrumentationRunner.

For a detailed example see the [AndroidTestingBlueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint) example project on github.

The solution from @johan-stuyts that got bounty works fine (or at least it did with the android gradle plugin 1.2). But it uses private APIs and creating a separate module is easier and future proof.

Comment: That example project does not illustrate multiple test modules in a single project, in fact it does not build correctly.

Comment: Example project is not working and there is no configuration for different TestRunner.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, I used gradle's taskGraph. Based on your statement "My project has 2 different groups of tests." I'm going to assume you have different tasks defined, I'll call them testGroupOne and testGroupTwo:

```
task testGroupOne{
}
task testGroupTwo{
}
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if(taskGraph.hasTask(testGroupOne)){
        testInstrumentationRunner "my.custom.TestRunner"
    } else if (taskGraph.hasTask(testGroupTwo)){
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

This enables you to set the value of testInstrumentationRunner after configuration but before execution.

Comment: The android plugin has then already been configured and uses the testInstrumentationRunner from the configuration phase.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution, but maybe this will make things a bit less cumbersome for you: It does not allow you to run the tests with both test runners in the same build. If you want that you would have to clone all task instances of `DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask`, which, in my opinion, is too complex and fragile.

This works for me (Gradle 2.4 and Android build tools 1.2.3). It uses internal APIs, so it is possible that this no longer works with the next release of the Android build tools.

You should modify the tasks generated by the Android plug-in after the project has been evaluated. The changes will then be used by the test tasks. The property that actually changes the used test runner is `task.testVariantData.variantConfiguration.testedConfig.mergedFlavor.testInstrumentationRunner`. Instead of making these changes during the configuration phase (i.e. outside a task), the changes are applied using a task, so your test runner is only used when requested. By forcing the test tasks to run after `useMyTestRunner` (if the latter is part of the build), the class name of the test runner will have been changed when a test task starts:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    task useMyTestRunner << {
        tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.class) { task ->
            task.testVariantData.variantConfiguration.testedConfig.mergedFlavor.testInstrumentationRunner = 'com.mycompany.MyTestRunner'
        }
    }

    tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.class) { task ->
        task.mustRunAfter useMyTestRunner
    }
}
```

You can now run the tests using the default test runner configured for the flavor(s) with:

```
gradle :myApp:connectedAndroidTest
```

When you want to run the tests with your test runner use:

```
gradle :myApp:connectedAndroidTest :myApp:useMyTestRunner
```

I did not add checks for `null` for any of the properties retrieved using `task.testVariantData.variantConfiguration.testedConfig.mergedFlavor.testInstrumentationRunner`. You should add them for robustness. I think at least `testedConfig` needs attention. See `getInstrumentationRunner()` at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/VariantConfiguration.java

You can use an import for `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask` at the top of your build file, so you only have to use the simple name of the class.

Comment: Could you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163964/how-to-combine-different-testinstrumentationrunner

Comment: @StuartDTO: It has been a while since I have done something with Android and Gradle, and much has changed since then. So I cannot answer this now. Let's hope someone else will help you. Your question is very new, so give it a bit of patience.